# how to draw text on a image

Tags: uiimage

I have a UIView that i want to pres a button and then i will have a text box or a label that the user can change and move...
Any one know where to start?

Comment: which technology you are using?

Answer (score 1):

For display purpose, just put a transparent UITextField on top of the UIImageView.